# Dropping temporary table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. When I want to create a temporary table named `#TBL1`, or rerun my code, I get this error:

> There is already an object named '#TBL1' in the database

So I added this code to my query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.#TBL1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.#TBL;
```

But it shows the same error message

Please give me a clue is to what is wrong

Comment: Try without `dbo.` anywhere. But also try checking `OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBL')` … did you find this code somewhere, if so, please tell us where so we can help correct them…

Comment: I'm surprised that the temporary table alreqdy exists; temporary tables are stopped once the scope or connection that created the table ends. When are you getting this error exactly? If you were on a more recent version of SQL Server (2012 has literally days of extended support left) you could use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure OBJECT_ID looks in the right place. Temporary tables live in tempdb:

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TBL1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
   DROP TABLE dbo.#TBL; 
 END
```

Also seems there is a typo (#TBL1 vs. #TBL).

And while I am normally am a big fan of schema prefixes, for #temp tables it’s not necessary and actually hampers readability IMHO.

Comment: I didn't even know you could put a schema prefix on a temp table, you live and learn https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ce7f983e0da5d6754eb1fc0148b64f4 It really doesn't work like you'd think it might, it's just completely ignored

Comment: Thank you for paying attention. Your advice solved my problem, but now I am getting  another error about permission issues